# react-native iOS Production JS Bundle

Tags: react-native

When testing my Android app I had the option to load between development & production bundles.

Does anyone know if you can do they same for IOS? I've changed the build scheme in Xcode to release but it's still loading the development bundle.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

For loading the correct file you actually need to edit the AppDelegate.M file in Xcode. The code which is down here will check if the build settings are debug (so it loads the network file) or release (load the local bundle)

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
    jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
```

Before you can set the jsCodeLocation you need to generate the correct file. You can do this with the following command:

```
node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --entry-file='index.ios.js' --bundle-output='./ios/YourApp/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'
```

This will put the main.jsbundle in the ios folder (which is in the root of your react native project I assume)

After you've done the steps above you can build and deploy your app and try it out :)

Mark

Comment: Hi Mark, I've done that - it's still loading the development bundle. If I comment out the #ifdef DEBUG I get the following error: No bundle URL present

Comment: Hello, please check you are loading the correct file, the name in URLForResource in the AppDelegate.m must match the same name as your --bundle-output file.

Comment: When you run `react-native run-ios --configuration Release`, should that automatically create the `main.jsbundle` file in the correct location so you can use the changes in `AppDelegate.M`? My  `main.jsbundle` hasn't been updating in some time even though I've ran `--configuration Release` multiple times.

Comment: To expand on the above, the docs state `This will now reference the main.jsbundle resource file that is created during the Bundle React Native code and images Build Phase in Xcode`, so if my `main.jsbundle` file is not being updated then I assume there is a problem in my build phase??